# Create a new column based on other column and calculations

Tags: python, pandas, math

Here is my dataframe : 
df

ID  AU
1   0
2   1
3   2
4   0
5   3
6   4
7   1
8   2
9   5
10  2
11  4
12  1
13  5
14  3

I want to create a new column 'Score' based on column 'AU' by using some conditions. The conditions are:

1. If 'AU' = 0, 'Score' will be 0
2. If 0 < 'AU' <= 4, 'Score' will be (1-AU)*(1-0.5)+0.5
3. IF 'AU' > 4, 'Score' will be (1-AU)*0.2+0.2

And finally the expected resut is:

ID  AU  Score
1   0   0
2   1   0,5
3   2   0
4   0   0
5   3   -0,5
6   4   -0,4
7   1   0,5
8   2   0
9   5   -0,6
10  2   0
11  4   -0,4
12  1   0,5
13  5   -0,6
14  3   -0,5

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, and presumably you made an attempt at this. What were the errors with your attempt?

Comment: Did you try `np.where`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `np.select` with `eval`

```
s1=(df.AU>0)&(df.AU<=4)
s2=df.AU>4
df['Score']=np.select([s1,s2],[df.eval('(1-AU)*(1-0.5)+0.5'),df.eval('(1-AU)*0.2+0.2')],default=0)
df
Out[136]: 
    ID  AU  Score
0    1   0    0.0
1    2   1    0.5
2    3   2    0.0
3    4   0    0.0
4    5   3   -0.5
5    6   4   -1.0
6    7   1    0.5
7    8   2    0.0
8    9   5   -0.6
9   10   2    0.0
10  11   4   -1.0
11  12   1    0.5
12  13   5   -0.6
13  14   3   -0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply` function:

```
import pandas as pd

def computeScore(x):
    assert x >= 0
    if (x == 0):
        return 0
    elif ((x > 0) & (x <= 4)):
        return (1-x)*(1-0.5)+0.5
    return (1-x)*0.2+0.2

d = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
     'AU': [0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 2, 4, 2, 5, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df["Score"] = pd.Series(df.AU).apply(computeScore)
```

API Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html